# Is there a way to turn off JIT compiler and is there a performance impact by doing so?

Tags: jvm, interpreter, bytecode, compiler-optimization, jit

What does it mean for a Java program to be JIT'ed and does it make the execution a lot more faster? Or are there bytecodes which are not JIT'ed?

Answer (score 20):

There is two ways to disable the JIT

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE
```

or this will almost never compile anything

```
-XX:CompileThreshold=2000000000
```

or on IBM JVM

```
-nojit
```

Disabling the JIT can slow down your code a lot e.g. 50x but not always. If you spend most of your time doing IO or GUI updates you might find it makes little difference.

Comment: I am learning java and have so many doubts regarding most of the stuff.....thank you for your answer. :) further I would like to know what compiler comes in to play when we disable JIT?

Comment: @CoDerus disabling the JIT means there is no compiler. Instead the code is only run in interpreter mode.

Comment: I was a bit surprised that this ancient `java.compiler` property still works despite you can’t really use it to specify an actual compiler implementation, so I investigated a bit and found [JDK-8227229](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8227229) which explains a bit of the history and also reveals the surprising fact that specifying `-Xdebug` makes `-Djava.compiler=NONE` ineffective, so using `-Xint` has always been the more reliable option.

Answer (score 12):

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE),

```
-Xint
```

Runs the application in interpreted-only mode. Compilation to native code is disabled, and all bytecode is executed by the interpreter.

The `java.compiler` system property is known by [Compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Compiler.html) class before Java 9. In [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Compiler.html) it's marked as `@Deprecated`.

Answer (score 3):

For IBM the correct option is -Xnojit or -Xint

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13907839)

Comment: When I wrote his answer I was not allowed to comment.  Otherwise, I would have.

Answer (score 1):

In HotSpot VM JIT compilation can be disabled with the option [`-XX:-UseCompiler`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/compiler/compileBroker.cpp#l580) which skips compiler threads initialization.

It is `true` [by default](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/runtime/globals.hpp#l1492):

```
product(bool, UseCompiler, true,                                          
        "Use Just-In-Time compilation")
```