# Java APPCRASH on network device state changed

Tags: java, networking, jvm, event-log, crash

My Java application crashes when I changed network device state (for example WiFi disable -> enable). The Event Viewer logs Application Error Event ID 1000. I have compared java sources and they are identical.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          04/10/2016 16:29:54
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      LAPTOP22470825
Description:
Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 6.0.430.1, time stamp: 0x51308a12
Faulting module name: jvm.dll, version: 20.14.0.1, time stamp: 0x5130b042
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0009f9c3
Faulting process ID: 0x758
Faulting application start time: 0x01d21e53cfd564aa
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
Report ID: 65c2cfeb-8a47-11e6-8335-0023564c8003
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-10-04T15:29:54.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>12906</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>LAPTOP22470825</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>java.exe</Data>
    <Data>6.0.430.1</Data>
    <Data>51308a12</Data>
    <Data>jvm.dll</Data>
    <Data>20.14.0.1</Data>
    <Data>5130b042</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>0009f9c3</Data>
    <Data>758</Data>
    <Data>01d21e53cfd564aa</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll</Data>
    <Data>65c2cfeb-8a47-11e6-8335-0023564c8003</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Where should I look for solution for this issue? Is there stored more readable logs?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to see if it is caused by just-in-time compiling.  If so, then using the command line java option -Xnojit on the IBM JVM, or options listed here for othe JVMs: [IS there a way to turn off JIT compiler and is there a performance impact by doing so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315960/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-jit-compiler-and-is-there-a-performance-impact-by-doi)

I think -Xint might work on both Oracle and IBM.

There are potentially other logs, typically known as dumps.  For IBM, you can find them according to the info here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007948
Or here http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60/diag/tools/tools_intro.html

For Oracle, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tools-141261.html
Section 4 on system crashes.