# Logging all method calls by modifying OpenJDK

Tags: logging, java, jvm-hotspot

I'm trying to modify the OpenJDK 9 in order to log every method called by a Java program, in particular I'm experimenting with a very simple class with a `main` that calls one of its own static methods that prints a line on stdout once every two seconds (waiting done with `Thread.sleep`)
After reading [this blog post](https://gbenson.net/?p=118), I've put logging code inside `javaCalls::call`. It works, logging lots of calls from the JVM start up to the call to Myclass.main, then it stops (my program keeps printing). After exiting the program with `CTRL^C`, the logging resumes and logs methods such as `Thread.exit`.
I then tried another way: to instrument `hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/bytecodeInterpreter.cpp` at every bytecode for invoke. Worse than before, this doesn't print anything.

At first I was relying on the new JDK 9 logging feature, but then I decided to append directly to file to exclude the possibility that the log was disabled at some point.

I have two questions:

1. Have I misinterpreted the cited blog? Shouldn't my first attempt be enough to log everything?
2. Do you have any suggestion for a point where I have better chances of accomplishing my goal?

Comment: That article says “it will call JavaCalls::call (in javaCalls.cpp) *to bridge from VM code to Java code*”. It does not say that every invocation will be done through this method. After all, the whole purpose of inlining is to get rid of such overhead…

Comment: @Holger thank you, I think I get it. May I ask if in your opinion the second idea of instrumenting the interpreter is wrong? Or have I just missed the point in the code?

Comment: I never tried to modify the JVM code. But to me, it sounds like that approach can only work, if you disable the JIT, which is rarely feasible.

Comment: I see. So, if I understood, JIT compiled code would be called without passing through some sort of helper or trampoline in bytecode firts for method calls?

Comment: I just tried `-Djava.compiler=NONE` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315960/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-jit-compiler-and-is-there-a-performance-impact-by-doi) and nothing seems to change.

Comment: You could bytecode instrument all method calls. It will work regardless if it executed in the interpreted, C1 or C2. See 
http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~msb/cs239-tutorial/