# why adding first item into collection much slower than second?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, collections, timing

I came across huge performance difference between adding 1st and 2nd item into a collection(tried `ArrayList` and `HashSet`), but I cannot explain why. Have searched but didn't find any answer.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // also tried HashSet
        // also tried new ArrayList<>(2)
        ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        collection.add("a");
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        collection.add("b");
        long t3 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(t2 - t1) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(t3 - t2));
        //typical output:
        //4399
        //1201
    }
}
```

Some guess:

- because collection is lazily initialzed when adding 1st item?
- or I used the wrong way to measure performance?
- or related to how jvm works(which is beyond my knowledge)?

Environment: jdk11, win10, intellij.

Comment: well there might be a ton of reasons. In general this is not a good benchmark, the JVM has to warm up, load classes and compile the code. And that might happen in some unspecified order.

Comment: The difference is 3µs, surely not noticable even in hard real-time environments. To get more relevant results, create a test program where the execution times are some seconds, and then see whether there's still a significant difference between first and second addition (still probably not a valid benchmark, but much better than the current test). And then use a profiler to see what part of the program consumes the CPU time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Of lazily initialized. when you are running this line

```
ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
```

it is only holding a reference to the list but the actual memory allocation does not happen for that list. But when you are adding the very first element to the collection then it is first allocating memory for the next 10 elements of the  List (10 is the default size of array list) after that adding the first value.
Results of the next 9 elements will take less time to insert but again for the 11th element, it will take more time than previous.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
          long t1 = System.nanoTime();
          collection.add("a");
          long t2 = System.nanoTime();
          System.out.println("Index : "+ (i+1) +": Time: "+ String.valueOf(t2 - t1));
    }
    /** Output:
     *  Index : 1: Time: 6800
        Index : 2: Time: 800
        Index : 3: Time: 500
        Index : 4: Time: 700
        Index : 5: Time: 600
        Index : 6: Time: 500
        Index : 7: Time: 600
        Index : 8: Time: 600
        Index : 9: Time: 500
        Index : 10: Time: 500
        Index : 11: Time: 2800
        Index : 12: Time: 500
     */

}
```

Comment: Even if you are right with the lazy initialization of the `ArrayList` class, you **cannot** run microbenchmarks like this. The code is essentially wrong. There is JIT in your way, and I/O is also so expensive that I suspect that the cost of the first `System.out.println` will be much more relevant for the low speed of the first operation.

Comment: Reference to OpenJDK11 implementation of [ArrayList](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) confirms that it is lazily allocated when `add(E e)` gets called, even in the default case when size is supposed to be 10. Completely agreed on the benchmark comments though, there's a reason the documentation says `The add operation runs in **amortized** constant time`.

Comment: @Avinash Yes, the collection is lazily initialized, but no, your code does not "prove" it. Hint: try your code with `new ArrayList<>(100)` instead of `new ArrayList<>()`: the first iteration is still times bigger than the second one.

Comment: @HonzaZidek There is no I/O between the timings. How should the effect of JIT be eliminated?

Comment: @AlexeyVeleshko Yes, you are right, there is no I/O between the timings, it's a valid point.  How to completely disable JIT - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/34315960/2886891. How to eliminate JIT - read my answer and study the link provided.

Comment: @shriakhilc the lazy allocation does not happen “even” in the default case, but *only* then.

Answer (score 4):

All your three guesses are correct :)

You are asking a good question. Just be warned: Microbenchmarks are **so treacherous** that you may easily come to a completely wrong assumption about the speed of the parts of your code. You were right with the lazy initialization, but it was rather a good luck :)

The most important thing is that you are right with your guess that you "used the wrong way to measure performance".

You cannot measure the speed of a Java application like this. It is simply not possible. The process is too random and too dependent on many other factors, especially JIT (Just in Time optimization) in runtime.

Try have a look e.g. here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness, try to run it and think how it works.

TL;DR: The JVM must be be first "warmed-up", then you have to run the tested code multiple times and calculate an average time. And still there might be a lot of optimization which causes that some code is not executed at all :)

If you don't want to play with the microbenchmark library, at least move your code into a method and call the method 20 times. I just did it (only replaced `\n` with `---`) and the result is like this:

```plaintext
10800---1400
1500---200
600---100
500---100
700---100
400---100
400---100
400---100
400---100
500---100
400---100
400---100
400---100
400---100
300---100
400---100
300---100
500---100
400---100
300---100
```

As you can see, the warming up was the most significant factor. However the influence of the lazy initialization is also visible.

Comment: OP does not ask how to measure the "speed" of a Java application but rather why results that he gets are as they are. Whatever is "too random", results are consistently differing by a ratio of at least 2:1.

Comment: @starikoff But the way of measuring the speed is crucial for the question! You cannot even state with certainty that "adding the 1st and 2nd item differs in time" based on the method the OP provided! If you start a question with a wrong assumption, you must first fix the assumption before you may continue. And the OP is correct in his three guesses :)

Comment: you look at a clock 3 times and note down the time deltas. The first is 2-6 times bigger than the second. You do it a 100 times and you always get it this way. Why is it not legitimate to ask why?

Comment: @starikoff It *is* indeed legitimate to ask why! I just wanted to warn the OP that the question was based on principally corrupted assumption. And he himself guessed correctly that he "used the wrong way to measure performance"! Here the OP was also right with the lazy initialization issue, however he was just lucky! Microbenchmarks are **so treacherous** that you may easily come to a completely wrong assumption about the speed of your code.

Comment: @starikoff See my edit, hopefully I expressed myself clearer now.

Comment: thanks, for the general guides to java benchmark, though @Avinash's answer better explains **this** question.